# Não conseguindo obter o valor selecionado no Select do Material-UI(MUI)

Tags: java, react, select, material-ui

Eu possuo um componente em React onde estou fazendo um componente de select que recebe um objeto neste formato:

```
{
    "status": "Ok!",
    "message": "Successfully fetch data!",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "createdAt": "2023-11-10T17:35:17.000Z",
            "firstName": "Teste",
            "lastName": "Teste",
            "cpf": "123.123.123-12",
            "email": "12312312323",
            "phone": "12 31231-2321"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "createdAt": "2023-11-10T17:35:29.000Z",
            "firstName": "Teste",
            "lastName": "Teste2",
            "cpf": "123.123.123-12",
            "email": "12312312323",
            "phone": "12 31231-2321"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "createdAt": "2023-11-10T17:36:38.000Z",
            "firstName": "Teste",
            "lastName": "Teste3",
            "cpf": "123.123.123-12",
            "email": "12312312323",
            "phone": "12 31231-2321"
        },
    ]
}
```

Meu componente:

```
return (
                <Select placeholder={placeholder}>
                    {carOwnersOptions.result && carOwnersOptions.result.map((owner) => (
                        <Option key={owner.id} value={owner.id}>
                            {owner.firstName} {owner.lastName}
                        </Option>
                    ))}
                </Select>
        );
```

Eu não consigo obter o valor que foi selecionado no meu campo de select, gostaria de obter o id, firstName e lastName. Testei com onChange, de várias formas, e não consegui.